# Change google charts options not working

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I've created a google chart and the data is pulled from a database and structured to meet the requirements of the chart, however, for some reason, whenever I try change the options for the chart it just wont work.
I need to move the legend to below the chart and make the point size on the chart 30 pixels.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Aspect');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Leaner');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Norm');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Grade');

      data.addRows([['Agility ', 11.5, 10, 11.5]]);
      var options = 
      {
        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
        chart: {title: 'Student Results'},
        legend:{position: 'bottom', textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 16}},
        pointSize:30,
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('line_chart'));

      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
    }
</script>

<div id="line_chart" style='width:calc(100% - 80px); height:400px; margin:auto;'></div>
```

Any suggestions on why the legend wont move or point size wont change, the chart data can have many aspects (x axis value), I need to point-size to change so that it wont look blank with just a aspect (x axis value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are several options that simply don't work in *Material* charts

and it appears `Line` requires two data points per series before drawing anything

I would recommend using `'corechart'` instead

there is an option for `theme: 'material'` to get the base look and feel *close* to a *Material* chart

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Aspect');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Leaner');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Norm');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Grade');

    data.addRows([['Agility 1', 11.5, 10, 11.5]]);

    var options = {
      chartArea: {
        width: '90%'
      },
      height: 600,
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
        textStyle: {
          color: 'black',
          fontSize: 16
        }
      },
      pointSize: 30,
      theme: 'material',
      title: 'Student Results',
      vAxis: {
        viewWindow: {
          min: 0,
          max: 15
        }
      },
      width: '100%'
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages:['line', 'corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div>Core Chart</div>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div>Material Chart</div>
<div id="line_chart"></div>
```

Comment: That works perfectly, I battled for 3 days, so glad that I can finally move on, really appreciate the help :)